# How can I changed the style of acell?

Tags: wpf, telerik, radgridview, selectionchanged

I use the cell selection changed event to set style of the cell in rad grid view. the problem is that the changing is not consistent.for example by selecting entire row the previously changed cells is lost!
how can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can change the Selection Unit for the grid from both row and cell to just cell.

http://docs.telerik.com/devtools/wpf/controls/radgridview/selection/mixed-selection